# Code::Blocks and Armadillo Linking: cannot find -lopenblas.lib

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, armadillo

I want to link armadillo-11.4.0 to Code::blocks C++ project in Windows 11. I already gave the path to include folder and library folder using Project Build options>>Search directories. Also, in Build options>>linker settings I added the "libopenblas.lib" which is the precompiled openblas library I found in the armadillo\examples\lib_win64 folder. However, When I compile the example code given below, I get the following error.

**ld.exe||cannot find -lopenblas.lib|**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int
main()
  {
  std::cout << "*** smoke test start" << std::endl;

  uword N = 5;

  mat A = reshape(regspace(1, N*N), N, N);

  A.diag() += randu<vec>(N);

  mat B;

  bool status = expmat(B,A);

  A.print("A:");
  B.print("B:");

  std::cout << ((status) ? "*** smoke test okay" : "*** smoke test failed") << std::endl;

  return (status) ? 0 : -1;
  }
```

Can someone explain me how to compile this successfully?

Comment: Do you have armadillo\examples\lib_win64 in the linker’s library search paths?

Comment: @Russell Hynes: Yes, I have added the path armadillo\examples\lib_win64 to the Search Directories> Linker. I have both libopenblas.lib and libopenblas.dll files in the lib_win64 folder. Yet, it cannot be compiled. 
When I linked armadillo with Visual studio, it worked perfectly. I wonder what I'm doing wrong in code blocks.

Comment: what c++ compiler are you using with code blocks?

Comment: @Russell I am using the GNU GCC Compiler